# Decide which window the slime buffer opens in?

Tags: buffers, slime

I usually have emacs open in 4 sections

| code | slime |
| --- | --- |
| code | terminal |

When I am setting up, and i open slime with `M-x Slime`, it opens up in one of the other buffers.

Question -- How do I control which buffer slime opens in?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Only one question per post, please. Please keep one of your questions here and move the other to a separate post. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slime-start` (in `slime.el`) calls `pop-to-buffer`.  One idea would be to change that to `switch-to-buffer`, and another idea would be to customize the `display-buffer-alist`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Zen-of-Buffer-Display.html

`switch-to-buffer` will target the current / selected window.  See also `set-window-buffer` as a way to control which window is targeted.  `display-buffer` with the appropriate targeting function and alist settings, can also be used to target a specific window.

How did I ascertain which slime function calls `pop-to-buffer`?:

**STEP #1**:  Install `slime` and set the `load-path` correctly.

**STEP #2**:  `(require 'slime)`

**STEP #3**:  `M-x find-function RET slime RET`

**STEP #4**:  Move the cursor to `slime-start*` and repeat the process ... `M-x find-function RET slime-start* RET`.  By placing the cursor on the desired function, the default for `find-function` will be the function at point.

**STEP #5**:  Move the cursor to `slime-start` and repeat the process ... `M-x find-function RET slime-start RET`.

**STEP #6**:  We see that the last line of `slime-start` is `(pop-to-buffer (process-buffer proc))`.

If the O.P. chooses to modify `slime.el` directly, then check to see whether there is a corresponding byte-compiled file with the name `slime.elc`.  If so, then re-byte-compile the modified Lisp file with `M-x byte-compile-file`.  Then, restart Emacs or evaluate the modified function so that the current instance becomes aware of the modification.

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thank you.